# Is an entire function "determined by" its maximum modulus on each circle centered at the origin?

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation, entire-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function, and $$M_f(r)=\max_{|z|\leq r}|f(z)|$$ denotes its maximum modulus on the circle centered at the origin with radius $r>0$.

It's clear that for any entire functions $f(z)$ and $g(z)=e^{i\varphi}f(e^{i\theta}z)$, $M_f\equiv M_g$, where $\varphi$ and $\theta$ are real constants.

For $f(z)$ and $h(z)=\overline{f(\overline z)}$, we also have $M_f\equiv M_h$.

My question is, for any entire functions $f(z), g(z)$ that satisfying $M_f\equiv M_g$, could we always transform $f$ into $g$ by the rotation and reflection(or some composition of both) as above? If not, is there any other universal transforms that keeps $M_f$?

Comment: Is the conjugate of a holomorphic function holomorphic?

Comment: $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n, \overline {f(\bar z)}=\sum \bar a_nz^n$ is entire

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn’t see the “inner” conjugate. Thanks!

Comment: @Martin definitely interesting- my instinct is that the answer is no (there is no simple way to relate such) and will think about

Comment: Now asked on Math Overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/421231/116247.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an old classical conjecture of Blumenthal. The most recent results are here:

Hayman, W. K.; Tyler, T. F.; White, D. J.
The Blumenthal conjecture. Complex analysis and dynamical systems V, 149–157,
Contemp. Math., 591, Israel Math. Conf. Proc., Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2013.